# modify view of list in JS

Tags: javascript, custom-list

I have this code:

```
  window.SFW = window.SFW || {};
  window.SFW.urgentAlertsItem = {
  customItemHtml: function (ctx) {


    var urgentAlertsItemHtml = "<div class='urgent'><h2 class='name'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</h2>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='note'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Note+ "</div>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='profile'> <img src='" + ctx.CurrentItem.Profile+"' /></div>";
    var priority = ctx.CurrentItem.Severity;



// In the following section we simply determine what the rendered html output should be. In my case I'm setting an icon.



   if (priority.indexOf("High") != -1) {

    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='severity' style='background-color: #FF8000;width:90px;height:35px;position:relative;left:60px;  border: 2px solid #FF8000;'><img id='sevimg' src= 'http://sfwgcidev01/sites/Dev/Style Library/Style/images/High.png'/><p>" + priority + "</p></div>";

}

if (priority.indexOf("V.High") != -1) {

    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='severity' style='background-color: #FF0000; width:90px;height:35px;position:relative;left:60px;  border: 2px solid #FF0000;'><img id='sevimg' src= 'http://sfwgcidev01/sites/Dev/Style Library/Style/images/VHigh.png'/><p>" + priority + "</p></div>";

}


if (priority.indexOf("Moderate") != -1) {

    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='severity' style='background-color: #FFFF33; width:90px;height:35px;position:relative;left:60px; border: 2px solid #FFFF33;'><img id='sevimg' src= 'http://sfwgcidev01/sites/Dev/Style Library/Style/images/eye.png'/><p>" + priority + "</p></div>";

}
if (priority.indexOf("Low") != -1) {

    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='severity' style='background-color: #00FF00; width:90px;height:35px;position:relative;left:60px;  border: 2px solid #00FF00;'><img id='sevimg' src= 'http://sfwgcidev01/sites/Dev/Style Library/Style/images/info.png'/><p>" + priority + "</p></div>";

}


     urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<button class ='moreDet'>More Detail</button></div>"; 
    return urgentAlertsItemHtml;
}
};






(function () {

var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};

overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='urg'>";
overrideCtx.Templates.Item = window.SFW.urgentAlertsItem.customItemHtml
overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);


})();
```

Which prints out all of the items in my list. However I want it so it filters the list and only prints out a select number of items. So is there anyway to modify the view in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way would be to create a new View with all necessary filters and use it on the pages(as Webpart) and apply JSLink to the web part properties.

JSLink:
You could always add a conditional check within the JS but that might offset the paging and result in empty cells. For ex.

```
customItemHtml: function (ctx) {
   var _taskStatus = ctx.CurrentItem.Status;
   if (_taskStatus == "Completed")
      return  "";
   //...
   //rest of the logic continues here
}
```